# Is there a fusion category not Grothendieck equivalent to a unitary one?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, fusion-categories, unitary-fusion-category

We refer to the book *Tensor categories* by Etingof-Gelaki-Nikshych-Ostrik ([MR3242743](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3242743)) for the notion of (unitary) fusion category. Two fusion categories are *Grothendieck equivalent* if they have the same fusion ring.

**Question**: Is there a fusion category not Grothendieck equivalent to a unitary one?

The following citations (coming from above book) are almost on-topic, but not exactly, because they are about the existence of a certain structure on certain fusion categories, whereas above question relaxes up to Grothendieck equivalence, which is much weaker.

On page 284:

> We note that we do not know an example of a fusion category over
>   $\mathbb{C}$ which does not admit a Hermitian structure, or a
>   pseudo-unitary fusion category which does not admit a unitary
>   structure.

On page 76:

> Does every semisimple tensor category admit a pivotal structure? A
>   spherical structure? This is the case for all known examples. The
>   general answer is unknown to us at the moment of writing (even for
>   fusion categories over ground fields of characteristic zero).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, according to Andrew Schopieray. He just provided a categorifiable fusion ring, of rank 6 and multiplicity 2, without pseudounitary categorification (so without unitary categorification), in the following preprint called *Non-pseudounitary fusion*.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02958